# Passing object as parametar in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner and please show me how to pass the parameter object `Person` to `Button.Click` event. I'm using vb.net. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Class MyPersonClass
        Public Name As String
        Public Age As Integer
        Public Title As String
    End Class

    Public Sub DisplayPerson(ByVal person As MyPersonClass)
        Label1.Text = person.Name
        Label2.Text = person.Age.ToString()
        Label3.Text = person.Title
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: where and how do you assign value for your `MyPersonClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private ExamplePerson As MyPerson  

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ExamplePerson = New MyPersonClass 'thanks Chris Dunaway for the correction
    ExamplePerson.Name = "Test Name"
    ExamplePerson.Age = 36
    ExamplePerson.Title = "Title Name"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DisplayPerson(ExamplePerson)
End Sub
```

Comment: This will throw a NullReferenceException since you are not instantiating the object (using New) anywhere.

Comment: My bad. Fixed. Thank you. Too used to C++ :P

Answer (score 3):

You don’t – `Button1_Click` is an [*event handler*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx), you’re not supposed to call it manually. It *gets called*, with predefined parameters, when a certain event occurs. You cannot really adapt these parameters, simply because it doesn’t make sense: the event would no longer know how to call the handler.

You can easily write your own method and pass any object to it, of course. And you’ve done exactly that with `DisplayPerson`.

Comment: Hm, I want that when I push the button Button1 to show me values name, age and title. Could you please give me explain through code

Comment: @Jande87 *which* value’s? You haven’t told us that.